# Can you add a redirect url after requesting an email verification with the firebase Auth REST API?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a python backend interacting with the Firebase REST API. I'm able to get an email verification email sent, but clicking the link takes you to a page that says "Your email has been verified." Is there some way to have it so that the link takes you back to your app instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pass a redirect URL into to the email verification link for Firebase Authentication. It's a reasonable request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.

In the meantime the common ways to address the use-case is to [set up a custom email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) page.